# How can i build dynamic organizational chart?

Tags: php, orgchart

I'm trying to build an dynamic organizational chart with php. Do i need to build it myself or is there some tools for that?

specification: all the positions in the company are predefined in the org chart, we only add persons in the correspondent position.

I need your suggestions.

Thanks.

---

I have installed image_graphviz and graphviz in my computer. but i don't know how to use it actually. Because there is so few documentation.

Does anyone have ever done this job or have some relational materials??

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You could use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org)** and connect it to your php via [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz). You can generate graphs like these:
[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [graphviz.org](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/Genetic_Programming.png))</sub>  .

You can find more examples [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php)

Comment: Thanks. theomega, you mean image_graphviz for php??

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool called [Organimi](http://www.organimi.com/) that will accomplish this.  It allows you to create a role based org chart.  You also create a roster of employees from which you can add/remove employees to/from these roles.  The roster can be imported from csv or you can integrate an existing employee database via the API.

Answer (score 3):

We've used the [Google Organizational Chart Tool](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html) with some pretty good success.  The API and documentation are very clear.  It was very quick to get a simple static demo up and running, and not much more work to generate it dynamically from our corporate data.

Comment: The good thing about Google Visualization API in general is that your back-end ends up being pretty thin, you lean all the heavyweight to the browser, this means that if your designed your app as SOA you may be able to reuse services and focus on the front-end programming instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Mindmap software for this kind of the project. There are many of them online and the desktop versions. This small, list helps you to examine:
Freemind
Mindomo
Mind42
Conceptdraw MINDMAP
Mindjet
Xmind